# Download addins from SharePoint Store

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I would like to know if it's possible to download an addin from the SharePoint store to deploy it on our SharePoint on premises farm which is not connected to internet ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Access to the SharePoint App Store requires that the SharePoint servers themselves have access. SharePoint makes the callout and performs periodic license checks.

To answer your question, no, your SharePoint servers must have Internet access.